# VS HTML Designer Tag Hierarchy Links. Broken in all versions including 2010-or is it me?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Should this bar on the HTML designer show the tag name? It sometimes does!

Here's an [image](http://screencast.com/t/NTY1ZWY1OTgt) of what I referring to.

I thought for sure it must be a bug but considering that I heard that MS was rewriting the editor (designer too?) I am starting to question whether I know how to use it!

Note the "TD" tooltip on the bottom right. Shouldn't this "TD" appear on the bar on the far right where the mouse would be?

Comment: Sometimes it happes for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  If there's a reliable repro for it (i.e. if you can show to do it from a new or sample form), you should file the bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.  (Or you could file it anyways, but without a repro, it's hard to find and fix...)

Comment: I previously tried to report it, but they couldn't repro it so, as far as they were concerned, it didn't exist.

Comment: Yup, please file a Connect bug.